# Korbon tomid whilst Jews were travelling (as opposed to camping) in the desert

Tags: halacha, travel, korban, dor-hamidbar

The benei kehos carried the miizbeiach whilst the Jews travelled.  It would seem improbable that the mishkon was erected every day whilst they journeyed.  What happened with the sacrifice of the Daily korban tomid? Was it suspended whilst they journeyed?

Comment: Menachot 95 could be relevant.

Comment: The gemara (Chagiga 6a-b) describes a machlokes regarding whether the *olos* brought at Mount Sinai were *t'midim*. R' Akiva takes the position that the *korban hatamid* was brought at Mt. Sinai, and that it never ceased being brought from then on. The Ibn Ezra takes a middle position, that the *korban hatamid* was brought as long as the Jews were encamped at Mt. Sinai, but it was not brought the whole time the Jews were in the desert (Ibn Ezra, Sh'mos 29:42).

Comment: @Fred, you should post an answer, no?

Comment: Do you actually need the Mishkan to bring a karban? There are those who say we should bring the Pesach nowadays at the _har habayis_, notwithstanding the absence of a beis hamikdash.

Comment: What about Mosbe Rabeinu assembling and dismantling the Mishkan every day of the shiva yimei miluim?  Is that improbable in your opinion?

Answer (score 1):

In Eruvin - :דף סג - we learned that Yehoshua was punished for not bringing the Korban Tomid. Apparently after the battle at Ay there was no time/energy left to erect the Mishkan.

It would appear that otherwise it was brought daily - as Fred already mentioned - as is mentioned in Chagiag דף ו.

As a result it would seem that they did erect the Mishkan daily.

Comment: The statement in Eruvin isn't really a proof, because at that point the Mishkan was already set up in Gilgal (see Rashi there ד"ה וגמירי: "they were ambushing the city, and hadn't returned the aron that evening to its place in Gilgal").